# Serialize an object in C# and get byte stream

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, deserialization

I have an object, instance of a `Serializable` class. I was wondering how can you get this object as a byte stream?

I know I can use [`BinaryFormatter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5sbs8z9.aspx) and then use the `Serialize` method, but this method takes a `serializationStream` where it writes the serialized object. I want to be able to write it in a file/stream in a specific position so I would like to do something like:

```
obj = new Something(); // obj is serializable 
byte[] serialized = obj.serialize(); [*]
file.write(position, serialized)
```

Is there any way I can do the `[*]`, to take the bytes of the serialization of an object?

Comment: Could you serialize it to a MemoryStream instead? And then just grab stream's buffer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream();
var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
formatter.Serialize(m, new MyClass() {Name="SO"});
byte[] buf = m.ToArray(); //or File.WriteAllBytes(filename, m.ToArray())


[Serializable]
public class MyClass
{
    public string Name;
}
```